# How to create new array of objects from main one

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects and from that I am filtering on the basis of age and want the new array of object to not to have age

**Like this**

I have this array of oject

```
    let arrayObj =[
  { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"}
]
```

now using `filter` I am filtering the array with age like below

```
    let newArray = arrayObj.filter((el)=>{
  if(el.age>20){
    return el.name,el.email
  }
})
console.log(newArray)
```

the console is always showing every thing like this

```
[{
  age: 50,
  email: "mike@hotmail.com",
  name: "Mike"
},{
  age: 45,
  email: "mike@hotmail.com",
  name: "Joe"
}]
```

But I want

```
[{
      email: "mike@hotmail.com",
      name: "Mike"
    },{

      email: "mike@hotmail.com",
      name: "Joe"
    }]
```

I don't know what to do next to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with only `filter`

```js
let arrayObj =[
  { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"}
];

let newArray = [];
arrayObj.filter(e => { 
  if(e.age > 20){
    newArray.push({ name: e.name, email: e.email });
  }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to remove the age property after filtering. You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let arrayObj =[
  { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
  { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"}
]

let newArray = arrayObj.filter(e => e.age > 20).map(e => { 
  return {
    name: e.name,
    email: e.email
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: SO any how I have to use map with filter?, It is not possible with only filter?

Comment: `filter` only selects specific elements from an array based on a filtering function you specify (in this case `age > 20`). But you want to change the properties of the elements, basically change the object inside the array. This can only be done with `map`. So, `filter` to select based on your criteria, then `map` to change the object to the format that you want.

Comment: @viveksingh `filter` is used to find and return elements of the array, not modify it. `map` is used for building a new output based on each item of you original array. There may be a way to hack `filter` into doing this, but it would be going against the point of the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use map instea of filter

```js
let arrayObj = [
  { name: "Joe", age: 20, email: "joe@hotmail.com" },
  { name: "Mike", age: 50, email: "mike@hotmail.com" },
  { name: "Joe", age: 45, email: "mike@hotmail.com" }
];

const newArray = arrayObj.filter(el => el.age > 20).map(el => {
    return {"name": el.name, "email": el.email};
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Undefined first item from the array. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to do this, like so:

```
let newArray2 = newArray.map(el => {
    return {
        name: el.name,
        email: el.email,
    };
})

console.log(newArray2);
```

Comment: Can't we do it with filter only

Comment: No, filter is strictly for filtering elements, not modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```js
let arrayObj =[
      { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
      { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
      { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"}
    ]
   
             
    var result = arrayObj
    .filter(x => x.age > 20)  //Filter by age
    .map(y => {return {name: y.name, email: y.email};})  //Map only required properties

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do with `filter`, `map` methods and object destructuring to make code more readable. Alternate way to do is using just one method `reduce`.

```js
let arrayObj = [
  { name: "Joe", age: 20, email: "joe@hotmail.com" },
  { name: "Mike", age: 50, email: "mike@hotmail.com" },
  { name: "Joe", age: 45, email: "mike@hotmail.com" }
];

const res = arrayObj
  .filter(({ age }) => age > 20)
  .map(({ name, email }) => ({ name, email }));

console.log(res);

// Alternate way to do just with one method reduce
const res2 = arrayObj.reduce(
  (acc, { name, email, age }) =>
    age > 20 ? [...acc, { name, email }] : [...acc],
  []
);

console.log(res2);
```